# Logstash TCP Input Crashing

Tags: sockets, elasticsearch, tcp, logstash

We have a logstash (v2.3) setup with 1 queue server running RabbitMQ, 10 elasticsearch nodes and a web node for kibana.  Everything "works" and we have a large number of servers sending logs at the queue server.  Most of the logs make it in, but we've noticed many that just never show up.

Looking in the logstash.log file we'll see the following start showing:

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-07-15T16:21:34.638000+0000", :message=>"A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.\n  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Tcp type=>\"syslog\", port=>5544, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines charset=>\"UTF-8\", delimiter=>\"\\n\">, add_field=>{\"deleteme\"=>\"\"}, host=>\"0.0.0.0\", data_timeout=>-1, mode=>\"server\", ssl_enable=>false, ssl_verify=>true, ssl_key_passphrase=><password>>\n  Error: closed stream", :level=>:error}
```

This repeats about every second or so.  We initially thought maybe max connections limit was being met but a netstat only shows about ~4000 connections, and our limit should be upwards of 65,000.

**Why is this TCP plugin crashing so much?**

Everything I've read online hints towards this being an older issue that was resolved with newer versions of Logstash, which we've long since installed.  Whats confusing is that it is partially working, we're getting a ton of logs but also seem to be missing quite a bit.

Relevant conf file on Queue server:

**queue.mydomain.com:**

```
input {
  tcp {
    type => "syslog"
    port => "5544"
  }
  udp {
    type => "syslog"
    port => "5543"
  }
}

output {
  rabbitmq {
    key => "thekey"
    exchange => "theexchange"
    exchange_type => "direct"
    user => "username"
    password => "password"
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => 5672
    durable => true
    persistent => true
  }
}
```

We recently added UDP to the above conf to test with it, but logs aren't making it in reliably to it either.

**Just in case the Elasticsearch cluster conf is relevant:**

We have a **10 node Elasticsearch cluster**, setup to pull from the queue server, this works as intended and is on same version of Logstash as Queue server.  They pull from the rabbitMQ server with the conf:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    durable => "true"
    host => "***.**.**.**"
    key => "thekey"
    exchange => "theexchange"
    queue => "thequeue"
    user => "username"
    password => "password"
  }
}
```

**Anyone have any ideas for us to try to figure out whats up with tcp-input plugin?**

Thanks.